# ReactJS: Where in the project to put a Javascript function that is called when a onclick() event occurs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick

I am new to ReactJS, and I am working on the following component:

request-item.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import './request-item.scss';

class RequestItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="request-box">
                <div class="request-details">
                    <div class="information">
                      <h1>Table 9, 3:00PM</h1>
                      <h2>Request made 6 min ago.</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="status-button">
                        <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RequestItem;
```

This component is part of the following page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import RequestItem from '../../components/request-item/request-item.component';

import './requestlistpage.scss';

class RequestListPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Requests</h1>
                <div className="requests-container">
                    <RequestItem />
                    <RequestItem />
                    <RequestItem />
                    <RequestItem />
                    <RequestItem />
                    <RequestItem />
                    <RequestItem />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default RequestListPage;
```

When I click on the request button, I want the text in the button to change from 'Assistance Requested' to 'Completed'.

I know that this can be done through something like the following:

```
<button onclick="change()" type="button" id="button-1" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>

function change() 
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("button-1");
    if (elem.value=="Assistance Requested") elem.value = "Completed";
    else elem.value = "Assistance Requested";
}
```

If I was just working with HTML/CSS/Javascript, I would have the `change()` function in a separate file, and include this file in the HTML file.

However, since I am working with React, I am not sure what the convention is. My project structure is like the following:

```
src 
  > assets
  > components
  > pages
  > redux
```

If I had a function such as `change()` that is called whenever an `onclick()` event occurs, where would I include this function in a React project? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: If you are talking about kund of ’helper functions’ you could have a directory like ’utils’ and then import the needed methods like usual: import {myMethod} from ’./../utils/filename.js’

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution

```
class RequestItem extends Component {
  this.state = {
    status: "Assistance Requested", // Initial State
  }

  // Handle your state changes here
  toggleStatus = () => { 
    if (this.state.status === "Assistance Requested") {
      // UI re-renders when setState is invoked
      this.setState({ status: "Completed" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ status: "Assistance Requested" });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="request-box">
        <div class="request-details">
          <div class="information">
            <h1>Table 9, 3:00PM</h1>
            <h2>Request made 6 min ago.</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="status-button">
            <button type="button" class="request-button" onClick={this.toggleStatus}>
              {this.state.status}
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RequestItem;
```

In react, you handle changes to your UI using a combination of `state` and `props`. `Props` are passed down from parent to child, whereas `state` contains component level logic.

In your case, `changeStatus` is going to be the handler function, where you handle your logic changes when the button is clicked. All the UI related changes are stored in `state`, because whenever the `setState` function is called, `state` is updated and react will look for changes and call the `render` function again to update the UI.

You can learn the standard practices by going through the [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) on the website or looking at the [Main Concepts](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html).